# Sylvester domains

Tags: linear-algebra, reference-request, ring-theory

I'm an undergrad mathematics student and I'd like to request some books about Sylvester domains. Specifically I'd like to understand the fact that not all modules are Sylvester domains. I just proved Sylvester's nullity theorem and I didn't use any reference to the reals. Here's the proof:

> Let A and B be square matrices. Prove:
>   $$\text{rank} (AB) \geq \text{rank} (A)+ \text{rank}(B)-n$$

It is trivial to prove:
$$\text{rank} A \geq \text{rank}(AB)$$
The desired result then follows.

Answer (score 1):

Two things:

"Not all modules are Sylvester domains" Well, modules aren't usually rings at all. It would make more sense to understand "not all domains are Sylvester domains."

Secondly, the description of Sylvester's law of nullity talks about rectangular matrices, not just square matrices, so that throws some doubt on the above idea.

---

You can definitely find a proof more general than just the real numbers because *any field* will work, as shown by Sylvester. You can go even further than fields. After you leave fields behind, you need to be more careful with your intuition about how facts about matrices will work.

One book that has extensive information on Sylvester domains is [Cohn's Free Ideal Rings book](http://books.google.com/books?id=YLnF1CE4xDUC&pg=PA303&dq=%22Sylvester+domain%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=sPhUU5XmE5WzsQTA6YGgCQ&ved=0CCsQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=%22Sylvester%20domain%22&f=false) starting page 291. It gives Weyl algebras as examples of domains that aren't Sylvester domains.

Comment: I think $k[x,y,z]$ is a commutative example of domain that is not a Sylvester domain. It'd be nice to see a elementary explanation of why the OP's argument doesn't work in such a familiar case. Unfortunately, the OP contains many mistakes, so an explanation would have to start at the beginning, giving the correct definition of Sylvester domain and rank.

Comment: @JackSchmidt Is that so? I read that in two variables, $k[x,y]$ is Sylvester, but I don't know anything about such domains. Maybe three variables is enough to break one of the dimension conditions I saw?

Comment: (Caveat: I'm just skimming papers to understand the idea, and couldn't solve this exercise myself.) I read that the weak global dimension of a sylvester ring is at most 2. Hence 3 variables is apparently enough. I'm pretty sure Lam has something along these lines worked out, but I haven't had a chance to check if it was in a book or paper.